# InstancedBufferGeometry intersection not happening

Tags: three.js

I tried the **Instancedbuffergeometry**, it works awesome, 
Intersection is not happening in **InstancedBufferGeometry**, i checked in the threejs(r85) library, checkBufferGeometryIntersection function have the position value only, I think the offset and orientation value need to use with the position.

I have another doubt in it, i have used one rawshadermaterial only, then how i can highlight the selected geometry.

Can anyone guide in it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: CPU-based raycasting is not compatible with GPU-based instancing unless you write custom code to handle it. three.js r.85

Comment: what's wrong with the answers here, what were you expecting to get on github?

Comment: @pailhead. As WestLangley said, i am trying with custom shader programming.

Comment: He also said to not post on github and use SO.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the cpu is concerned (where you do the raycasting) those instances do not exist. You do however have your master geometry available. What you can do is, create another instance of `BufferGeometry` then create the same number of `Mesh` objects using that one instance of geometry. Use the same logic for instancing to place this into a scene. You don't render them, thus saving the overhead from multiple draw calls. You do have them available for intersection though as if it were normal geometry, because it is (you're just not rendering it).

Answer (score 1):

As [@pailhead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44527901/123219) already wrote, raycasting with instanced-geometries cannot work.

An alternative approach to achieve the same goal is to use so-called GPU picking. For this you render the scene into a framebuffer, using a special shader that will just output a unique color-value for every instance.

You can then sample the point under the cursor from that framebuffer and compute the instance-id from the color-value.

You can see an example for this technique [here](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes_gpu.html) or [here](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_instances_gpu.html).